# Datastax DevCenter 1.2 has fatal JRE error on startup on Debian 7.7 (Wheezy) using JDK 1.7_71

Tags: cassandra, debian, datastax

I get the following error when trying to start Datastax DevCenter on Debian 7.7 with JDK 1.7.

```
user@ahimsa:~/datastax/DevCenter$ ./DevCenter 

(java:17985): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkDisplayManager'

(java:17985): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(java:17985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

(java:17985): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(java:17985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(java:17985): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(java:17985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(java:17985): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkDisplay'

(java:17985): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(java:17985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion `parent_type > 0' failed

(java:17985): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(java:17985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f44ffb9973f, pid=17985, tid=139934893688576
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_71-b14) (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.71-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x5173f]  gdk_display_open+0x3f
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/bkarels/datastax/DevCenter/hs_err_pid17985.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug. 
#
```

I am not savvy enough with kind of error to even know where to start though I suspect one library is too new or another is too old for something to work.

This did look similar to many issues with eclipse Luna I found while looking around for this propblem.  So, I took a shot in the dark and added the following lines to DevCenter.ini.  (It didn't work, but figured what the heck...)

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

Does anyone know what else I might try to resolve an error of this type.  Thank you.

Comment: DevCenter does run on Eclipse. Try the suggestion here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434559
Please upgrade the version of glibc to >= 2.14. In case that is not possible, use eclipse with the environment variable SWT_GTK3=0.

Comment: were you able to give this a try? ^^

Comment: Sorry for this "non-comment", but not yet.  I have moved over to CentOS for now, but when I get back to my debian system I will try this fix and report back the results - thank you.